# DragScroll not working on my ASP.NET site JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, scroll, drag

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this script is not working on my site but it is working on JSFIDDLE

Here is my current script working in JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AhC87/90/

Here is the link to the site I am trying to design

http://blog.redeyeproject.com/WebForm1.aspx

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is on my sight simulate the dragscroll of the windows phone 7

or for those that don't know that then IPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can see in your site you are not including the required CSS.

```
#scrollareax {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#wrapperx
{
    background-image: url("img/wp7.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 800px;
    height:1500px;  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
}
```